# Flex WebView in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, webview, react-native

I don't want the "I agree" button to be visible until user scroll down the webview completely. Right "I agree" button is always shown in the bottom and webview has fixed width with a scroll.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 0,
    padding: 5,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default class PrivacyPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://testabcdef.com/privacy.html'}}
          style={{marginTop: 20, flex: 1}}
        />
        <Button>
          <Text>
            I agree
          </Text>
        </Button>
    </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with your approach mate. First off how do you ever expect the button not to be there? You've set a static flexbox layout with two elements which means they are both going to take up half the screen.

You need to inject some javascript into the webview to detect when the web view is at the end and only then show the button. React Native v0.37 added the onMessage functionality to allow you to post information back to the component. At that point you can display your button. I've made the button absolute position so that it will display over your webview.

```
// Inject JavaScript to detect scroll to end
const injectedJS = 
`
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         postMessage("Scroled to bottom")
     }
  });

  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    postMessage("Loaded on the bottom")
  }
`
export default class PrivacyPage extends Component {

  // Inject JavaScript to detect scroll to end
  state = {
    scrollEnd: false
  }

  _onMessage = () {
    this.setState({scrollEnd: true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://testabcdef.com/privacy.html'}}
          style={{marginTop: 20, flex: 1}}
          injectedJavascript={injectedJS}
          onMessage={this._onMessage}
        />
        {
          this.state.scrollEnd && 
            <Button style={styles.button}>
              <Text>
                I agree
              </Text>
            </Button>
        }

    </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This solution is a little complex and I recommend some cross-browser testing. Also presumes jQuery on the page you are loading. If not just refactor injectedJS to vanilla javascript

Comment: Thanks for the response.